# GestureScaleListener in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to increase the font zoom in a WebView using GestureScaleListener.  My WebView is within a Fragment. When I try GestureScaleListener on a fragment it doesn't work. My code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getActivity(), new simpleOnScaleGestureListener());
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "scaling", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
}
public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+detector.getScaleFactor(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        WebView wv = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.chaptercontent);
        WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
        settings.setTextZoom((int)(settings.getTextZoom() * detector.getScaleFactor()));
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I try the same code on a Activity, it works fine. How am I to make it work in a Fragment?

Comment: This could be related to the problem I'm also having, as reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13791904/scalegesturedetector-not-working-within-support-fragment-layout-on-froyo-2-2

Comment: This can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27647333/1870830