# ScaleGestureDetector not working for View within Fragment or ViewGroup layout on ICS and below

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-2.2-froyo

My application makes use of the support package to implement `Fragment`s on 2.2 upwards.

I have a `View` subclass (let's call it `ZoomableView`) that makes use of `ScaleGestureDetector` to detect pinch scaling events. This is done in the familiar way; that is, within `onTouchEvent()`, the `MotionEvent`s are passed to the detector using `mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event)`. A `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` is used to receive the scale events.

This `ZoomableView` class is always displayed as the sole `View` within a `Fragment` (let's call it `ZoomableFragment`). There are two use cases for it within the application. In one use case, the layout only consists of the `ZoomableFragment`, containing the `ZoomableView`. In the second use case, the `ZoomableFragment` will be displayed alongside another Fragment. This other `Fragment` happens to be housing a `MapView`, but the use of `MapView` isn't relevant to the problem (the problem still occurs if that second `Fragment` just contains an ordinary `View`).

The actual problem is that when testing on a pre-Jellybean device (specifically, a Froyo phone), when using the `Activity` that shows the twin-`Fragment` layout, the `ZoomableFragment`'s `ZoomableView` `ScaleGestureDetector` doesn't work. When I say 'doesn't work', I can see in the debugger that it processes the `MotionEvent`s, but none of the methods in the `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` are called. However, when using the `Activity` that contains *only* the  `ZoomableFragment`, the scale detection does work. If I try the application on my JellyBean devices, the twin-`Fragment` situation works absolutely fine; that is, the scale gestures are received.

I've searched around and the only issue I can find is where people have implemented `OnScaleGestureListener` and prevented it from working by returning false from `onScaleBegin()`. That's not my issue here.

So in summary, a `ScaleGestureDetector` doesn't call its listener when it should do when used within a `View` on a multiple support `Fragment` layout on Froyo (Android 2.2) and I assume up to and including ICS. If however the `Fragment` is the only one on the screen, the detector works fine. Furthermore, the problem doesn't exist whatsoever on my 4.1+ Jellybean devices.

**EDIT 1** In my twin-Fragment layout, the `ZoomableFragment` has always been placed on the right or bottom depending on orientation. An interesting observation I just made is that if I flip the layout such that the `ZoomableFragment` is at the top (rather than being the lower fragment) in the portrait orientation, or is on the left in horizontal orientation, then the scale detector works! I therefore suspect that this is something to do with the relation between the results of the `MotionEvent` `getRawX()` / `getX()` (and similar for Y) methods, when Fragments are used. But when I flip the layout like this, pinch zooming then doesn't work for the adjacent `MapView` `Fragment`! So, in summary, on Froyo it seems that `ScaleGestureDetector` is working only for a `View` contained in a `Fragment` that has a corner at 0,0 of the screen.

**EDIT 2** I've now answered this question myself with a simple solution I've come to after inspecting the source for `ScaleGestureDetector` on grepcode. Because the source even as far as ICS made use of `getRawX()` / `getRawY()`, I've updated this question to state as far as ICS being affected (I believe), rather than just Froyo as I first thought.

**EDIT 3** I've done a simple test to completely eliminate anything to do with `Fragment`s or anything else in my application. I took the simple Google `MapView` example project and simply changed the layout so that most of the screen is taken up by a `TextView` (weight 0.9) and a tiny `MapView` sits at the bottom with a weight of just 0.1. On my Froyo device, it will no longer pinch zoom. On my JB device, it does. So it seems I'm not going nuts, and I have come across a problem with the `GestureScaleDetector` on ICS and below (I think - certainly Froyo, anyway) for which the answer gives a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From inspecting the `ScaleGestureDetector` source code on grepcode, I see that Jellybean versions of `ScaleGestureDetector` do not make use of `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` methods of the `MotionEvent`. However, the earlier versions (Froyo, ICS etc) *do* make use of `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` for the purpose of slop calculation. This is where the problem is, because it means that the scale detector won't work if the target `View` doesn't have its top left near 0,0.

I got the `ScaleGestureDetector` to work on my custom `ZoomView`, even with it being placed on the right or bottom, by simply doing this within `onTouchEvent()`:

```
event.setLocation(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());    
mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
```

That causes adjustment of the `MotionEvent`'s internal offset variables such that the `getX/Y` and `getRawX/Y` methods now return exactly the same value. This prevents the slop calculation failing. The scale detector of course works with relative values and so it doesn't matter about the absolute values of X / Y. If you have further code that relies on the absolute values, you could do what I did to restore them after:

```
    float originalY = event.getY();
    float originalX = event.getX();     
    event.setLocation(event.getRawX(), event.getRawY());
    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    event.setLocation(originalX, originalY);
```

Furthermore, if I want to place my `Fragment` that contains a `MapView` on the bottom or right, I am already using a custom subclass of `MapView` anyway and so I just added this:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Work around required for ScaleGestureDetector.
    // Before calling the scale detector, perform a work-around that is needed for earlier APIs (I suspect
    // ICS and below, judging from inspection of ScaleGestureDetector) to make the MotionEvent give the 
    // same values for getY / getRawY and getX / getRawX. Wildly different values, caused by the View
    // being nowhere near the screen origin (i.e. the View is on the right or the bottom) means the 
    // detector doesn't work. 

    event.setLocation(event.getRawX() - getLeft(), event.getRawY() - getTop());
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Now, my `MapView` will pinch scale properly too, no matter where its `Fragment` is placed. (By the way - totally OT to this question, but in case anyone is wondering, I placed a `MapView` into a `Fragment` successfully using the `LocalActivityManager` solution as given on StackOverflow). **EDIT**: Actually, something is not 100% right: The map doesn't zoom around the center of the pinch gesture. I think it's to do with the ActionBar / notification bar height not being compensated for in the `getTop()`.